# Two apps installed with same package name

Tags: android

I am having a project in android studio in which I have only 1 package and while generating signed apk or debugging the app it installs 2 apk files, both are opening the same apk. I am not sure where the problem is. Can I get some suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.myapplication">
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,HardcodedDebugMode"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <activity android:name="com.example.myapplication.Activity.ImageViewer" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.Fragments.LeadManagement.ProcessingLeadUpdate"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.Activity.Splash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.Activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.schibstedspain.leku.LocationPickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/leku_title_activity_location_picker"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/leku_searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I think the problem is in the manifest file, so I am posting the manifest file here.
the `build.gradle` file in app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'json'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.goebl:david-webb:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.aliumujib:Nibo:2.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
implementation('com.schibstedspain.android:leku:6.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
implementation 'com.github.prabhat1707:EasyWayLocation:1.0'
implementation 'com.ryanjeffreybrooks:indefinitepagerindicator:1.0.10'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.developer-shivam:Crescento:1.2.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.camerakit:camerakit:1.0.0-beta3.11'
implementation 'com.camerakit:jpegkit:0.1.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31'
implementation 'com.github.PauloLinhares09:RetroPicker:1.2.3-Beta1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.2.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.hkk595:Resizer:v1.5'

}
```

Comment: Post bulld.gradle file in app level

Comment: Is ur device an root device? try __cat /data/system/packages.list__ , I don't think  you can install two apps with the same package name .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It feels like your application is picking up activity from some library.

1. Open the `AndroidManifest` file. click on `Merged Manifest` tab (in the bottom of the IDE).
2. Search for `Activity` having `LAUNCHER` intent-filter.
3. If there is any `LAUNCHER` `Activity` other than yours, that is the culprit.
4. You can modify or update your library `AndroidManifest` file and remove the activity from the launcher. If that library is not your own and you can't update the `AndroidManifest` file, you should try some other library.

Here it go, now create your signed build or debug, you will have only one launcher icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using customized SplashScreen, check into the AndroidManifest.xml file located on `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` and look for the intent-filter tag like this:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Certifies that you have only one statement of the preview snippet of code, preferably in the .SplashActivity statement, like this:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and your .MainActivity don't need to have intent-filter inside and will be like:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <!-- ! DON'T ENNABLE the intent-filter tag here in the same time with .SplashActivity
     to avoid duplicated app installation -->
    <!-- <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter> -->
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in my `AndroidManifest` I had the following line twice:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Just make sure you have it only once:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> // this line shouldn't be repeated in the AndroidManifest file
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```